# Encryption of Sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

I have a question about encryption of a Sqlite database.
I integrated [sqlcipher](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial) library into my iOS Application to decrypt a sqlite database.
Now, how can I encrypt an existing sql database (plaintext).
Can you give me all steps that I need to follow? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLCipher provides a convenience function called `sqlcipher_export` that will allow you to encrypt a plain text database.  An example is below, however you can find out more information within the documentation available [here](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export).

```
$ ./sqlcipher plaintext.db 
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY 'testkey'; 
sqlite> SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted'); 
sqlite> DETACH DATABASE encrypted;
```